# boot running low on space

Tags: boot, disk-usage

I got an error message saying "The volume `boot` has only  5.3 MB disk space remaining."

I looked through some of the answers on this site and the closes one I found referred to old linux kernels, but here's a list of all my kernels.

```
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-17-generic            3.5.0-17.28    i386   Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-18-generic            3.5.0-18.29    i386   Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-19-generic            3.5.0-19.30    i386   Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-21-generic            3.5.0-21.32    i386   Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-22-generic            3.5.0-22.34    i386   Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-23-generic            3.5.0-23.35    i386   Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-24-generic            3.5.0-24.37    i386   Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.5.0-17-generic      3.5.0-17.28    i386   Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.5.0-18-generic      3.5.0-18.29    i386   Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.5.0-19-generic      3.5.0-19.30    i386   Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.5.0-21-generic      3.5.0-21.32    i386   Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.5.0-22-generic      3.5.0-22.34    i386   Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.5.0-23-generic      3.5.0-23.35    i386   Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86
```

I don't think that's a lot so what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is a lot or not totally depends on the size of your boot partition. Each kernel takes about 25Mb of space in `/boot`, and you have 8 of them, so if your `/boot` is around 200Mb then everything can be explained easily.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove some of the older kernels. Typically people only keep the last 2 or 3 kernels and delete any older ones. You can remove the older kernels by following the steps in this question: [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)